# GET Facebook Page Fans

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of all my Facebook Page Fans.

All I can get from FQL is the total amount of fans for my facebook page. I can't know WHO my fans are?

I have tried this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/somepage
```

Anyone with an idea of how to know WHO my fans are? I.e. list the User IDs of all my fans for a specific page?

I also know that I can get more information about my fanpage using FQL and "insights", from there I can get "page_active_users" and so forth, but not a list of all my fans?

I know that Facebook doesn't support this (in public), but any ideas on how to get around it?

Comment: Here is [the best answer][1] I found on the subject. It even give you a PHP script


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10906320/244911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/members?limit=500&access_token=[oauthtoken]

Comment: It's those who liked it, not fans.

Comment: You are the king! Do you know if there is a limit to how many members you can get at a time? Since Coca Cola have 11 million fans =)

Comment: @serg well isn't that the same thing at Facebook? What's the difference between "fans" and "likers"?

Comment: @Erik Well there are two entities: likes (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like) and fans (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan). You can get likes by pageid but you can't get fans by pageid (can only check if some particular user is fan or not). Also there is 5000 limit on everything.

Comment: Using FQL (pages.isFan) I can see that a user from the list I get from https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/members is actually a fan of Coca Cola. Hence it gives me the real list of the fans, just like I wanted =)

Comment: I can do "paging":{"next":} to get more than 5000 fans for any given page.

Comment: Doesn't work any longer, I get "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column."

Comment: @Joelio i didn't get it using this link https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/members?limit=500&access_token=[oauthtoken]. Is the oathtoken same as accesstoken and whether it is to be given in square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get the UIDs of the users who have liked your page.

The UIDs of users are only available to third parties if the user performs a public action (post, comment or like on your page's feed), or if they auth an application.

This is why you can't query FQL with a page ID and get UIDs.

Comment: Yet the Facebook page itself does exactly this by calling https://www.facebook.com/ajax/browser/dialog/page_fans/?page_id=PAGE_ID&__a=1&causal_element=js_0&__asyncDialog=1&__user=USER_ID. Why them and not us? It's the same data and it's just as visible. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Its no more possible, thats why FB makes money ;-)

You can try to parse the AJAX call...