# retrieve the amount of likes in a facebook page status

Tags: facebook

I would like to enquire whether or not it is possible to retrieves the numbers likes of a facebook fan page status or links or photos to be like?

if there is, must there be an apps for this or a simple social plugins?

the main thing i would to do is that, when USER A likes my website, the amount of likes will increased right? The link that USER A liked, would appear in USER A's wall. What would happen if their friends likes the post where USER A likes my website, can i add up to that likes too?

Comment: hi your answer may be found from this post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page

Comment: hi, thanks for the reference.i think i must have misfire the question. changes are made

Answer (score 0):

When you access the Post object in the Graph API it has the count and details for both the comments and the likes - e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/47764841579_10150344908236580

Comment: hi  cool...how did you do that? The pages that i have do not allow the messages to be shown. Do you need an access token or something as the link you provided, doesnt seem to have the access token

Comment: You shouldn't need an access token to access the post, but i used my own access token to grab the post ID from my feed to get you that example