# Get all facebook ids of people who like our facebook page

Tags: facebook

How can we get a list of facebook ids of all the people that like our page?
Can we write some kind of code that goes over the page and gets them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a list of ALL the users who have liked a particular page using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) or [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql).

However, you can get a count of number of users who have liked your page by using:

```
SELECT fan_count from page where page_id = {page_id}
```

And you can also check whether any of the user in your friend list has liked a particular page or not (this requires additional `friends_likes` permission). This can be done by using:

```
SELECT created_time from page_fan where
page_id = {page_id} AND uid IN (uid1, uid2, ...)
```

---

**EDIT:** Just found out there's already a discussion going on regarding this on Stack Overflow. Take a look at this question: [Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page?rq=1)

Comment: I am not talking about graph api or fql. Is there a way to analyze the page itself somehow?

Comment: Did you consider using the Page Insights? I haven't used it but I think you might find some analyses there.