# page_fans_city returning no results from Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get access to the page_fans_city edge from the Facebook Graph API.

I am using the following query:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/StrandTowerHotel/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime

For some reason though it keeps returning no data when I am using the Graph API explorer.

*note: I am an admin/owner of the page*

Whats interesting though is that if I just query https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/StrandTowerHotel/insights/ then I get all the other metrics results returned but "page_fans_city" is not in the results.

**I have read through and tried the following solutions already posted on stack overflow but they don't seem to solve the issue.**

- [Getting number of people who like a page on facebook by city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679931/getting-number-of-people-who-like-a-page-on-facebook-by-city)
- [Facebook PHP Graph API not returning complete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146055/facebook-php-graph-api-not-returning-complete-data)
- [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

*Many thanks in advance for any help you can give me*

Comment: Is this page one of yours (i.e. are you in an administrative role)? If not this metric is not available to the public...

Comment: yes it is a page of mine. As I said I can get all the other insights metrics

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and bug fixing it ended up being the facebook api was just having issues. now working perfectly :(