# How to get the fans of a page I am admin of?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am admin of a page which has over 1000 likes. I want a list of all my fans. Is it possible to do this ? If yes how ?

I have been checking the facebook documentation and [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) but am not able to figure out anything. Please help.

What I want is a query like "select uid from page where page_id=xyz"+ access_token of the page

I have tried firing a query on the connection table, page table and page_fan table. But am not able to make any progress.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that is possible, and if so it shouldn't.
This is a privacy issue. A facebook page is meant to give you the ability to either connect to people with a common interest or to promote your cause/product/company.

You are able to get insights on your fans via: "https://www.facebook.com/{yourpagename}?sk=insights" which is fine to get some demographic data of your audience.

If you would get a list of your fans, you would basically have a template to send spam mails.
I don't say this is what you are trying to do, but if you could - everybody could.

This answer isn't very good, I know. But as far as I could research it there is no way to do that.

Comment: Bottner this has to be possible i.e. I should be able to see public information about my fans. For e.g. on my page I can see people who have liked my page. Now the only thing they need to do is provide and api for the same data to the same people. Which should be possible.

Comment: Try taking a look at:
[This Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page)

or:
[this google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=facebook+get+all+users+who+liked+a+page)

The first results are all stackoverflow results.