# Fetch Facebook "like-box" HTML without iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

The Facebook "Like Box" script modifies the page to insert an iframe even if you select the HTML5 or FBML options.

I need to position the elements in the box to suit client.  I have got the [direct link to the content I want](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FDhmkJ2TR0QN.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1859622e8%26domain%3Dwww.bazooka.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bazooka.com%252Fff95ef93%26relation%3Dparent.parent&header=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FBazooka%2F164213106940171&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&stream=false&width=680) (without the iframe).

I read the Graph API methods and some posts here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page).  It seems that you can easily tell if one person has "liked" a page but it does not let you fetch a list like the "like box" does.

The server I'm on here I have to do what I can client side.  If I were in a better position I would use curl to get me the HTML I want. Since that's not an option, here I am.

Since it is cross domain I assume I can't use AJAX to get content.  What is right way to get these elements into the page sans iframe?

Comment: Is the like box to be shown on a page or app which requires facebook authentication to use? Unless you are authenticating the user you cannot query the FB API to determine if the current user has liked the page or display a list of their friends in a style similar to the like box or even trigger a like. If they are authed, you'll need to recreate all of these features, if not, you're stuck with the standard like box and may need to manage your client's expectations.

Comment: No authentication, it's a store page.  If we could style the elements we'd be golden.  The like button displays only one's friends where as the like box shows profile pics for dozens of people who've liked the page.  It's that larger number of profile pics they want but they want it styled differently than the iframe.  It's nuts to me that they offer tabs for FBML and HTML5 versions but they all do the same danged thing - AND they don't have to.  They could draw the elements in a div like the like button does...