# How to see all fans of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, list, view

Is it possible to see a list of ALL the likers / fans of any Facebook page?
At this moment I only found a solution by using this:
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=55&id=TYPE PAGE ID HERE

Problem is that it only shows max. 100 likers.

Does anyone know more about this?

Best regards,
TT

Comment: it is not possible to get a list of all of them, mostly for privacy reasons i guess. there is no scenario where you would actually NEED that list anyway.

Comment: OK thanks for the fast reply!

Now I am happy with my current solution, but the problem is that the Like Box plugin always generates the same 'faces' / likers.
Any reason why it always shows the same faces and not random?

Comment: no, but i don´t think you can change that behaviour. i think it mostly shows friends of the user, if there are any. or maybe the latest fans.

Comment: Hmmm ok...

Do you know more about this script (first answer)?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page

Seems like there are some PHP scripts on the internet for it but I don't know if they still work and how to run them...

Comment: i dunno this script, but i am not sure if this is even legal to be honest....

Comment: To be honest, I also don't know if it's legal.
How can you run scripts like that?

Comment: I don't know exactly... paste the code into notepad and save it as a PHP file, and after that? :)

Comment: you need a webserver with php, or you need to install php on your computer...it´s not THAT easy.

Comment: Ok, it seems that there are also online script runners available but the scripts do not work anymore.
Hopefully there will come a new solution.

Comment: that is scraping and definitely not allowed on facebook