# How can I get the details of all fans of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Suppose that I am the administrator of a Facebook page, I want to get all of the profile details of a the people who "liked" my page. Is this possible? How?

So far, I have only been able to get aggregated data through the Graph API. For example, "number of like in the past week".

There are posts that claim that I can do this with the FQL API, but the documentation for the FQL seems to have been hidden on FB developer site.

Comment: No, that is not possible via API – as has been said here numerous times before already on similar questions.

Comment: @Cbroe I get mixed messages from the other answers. It seems that the story is different at different points in time.

Comment: cbroe is correct, and this would be a major privacy issue.

Answer (score 1):

FQL reference is not "hidden", it's here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql But there's no current official way to get the profile details of your Page's liker, because you'd need the permission to query the user data from the users.

There are some "hacks" as denoted at [Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page?rq=1) for example, but it's strongly advised that you don't use these. Facebook forbids scraping for example, and once Facebook changes its website, those methods are likely to stop working.