# Facebook - ids for page likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to get the identities of users who have liked a page through the Facebook graph api?  If so, what access permissions are required?

I have only been able to get the count via the /user edge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page)

Comment: those solutions are pretty old, do they still work?

Comment: i am pretty sure it´s not possible, at least not anymore. would be weird if it was, for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

That [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page) got one answer that is correct:

> Although you can't get a list of all the fans of a Facebook Page, you can find out whether a specific person has liked a Page.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios