# Remove Facebook Fans using Facebook API: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, xampp

I recently found out that I have a huge amount of Facebook bots that are following my Facebook Fanpage. As a result I have lots of trouble interacting with my fans.

Thus I wanted to to remove all the bots from my page using that instruction:
[Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page)

Unfortunately when I use that code I get an error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/schnooglestandalone/test.php on line 19

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/schnooglestandalone/test.php on line 19

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=251682891644217): failed to open stream: operation failed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/schnooglestandalone/test.php on line 19
```

This answer didnt help:

[file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

As you can see, I am running the script from a local XAMPP Server. My Facebook page is german.

Thanks guys

Comment: Don't use SSLv3. Use TLS.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks, but could you please give a little more information? I dont really know where to start solving the problem

Comment: Is it your local server or some hosting provider?

Comment: @WizKid I use XAMPP  . So I have a local server running that is sending the request to Facebook